# RRULE bug? only first item in list is used to generate occurrences

Tags: php, rrule

I am attempting to generate lists of occurrences for a specified RRULE in PHP using a couple of different libraries ([When](https://github.com/tplaner/When) and [RRule](https://github.com/rlanvin/php-rrule)).

The [RRule specification](https://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/recur.html) ([also see this](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rrule.html)) indicates we can specify multiple items separated by commas for most properties:

```
(BYSECOND" "=" byseclist )        
( ";" "BYMINUTE" "=" byminlist )        
( ";" "BYHOUR" "=" byhrlist )           
( ";" "BYDAY" "=" bywdaylist )          
( ";" "BYMONTHDAY" "=" bymodaylist )    
( ";" "BYYEARDAY" "=" byyrdaylist )     
( ";" "BYWEEKNO" "=" bywknolist )       
( ";" "BYMONTH" "=" bymolist )          
( ";" "BYSETPOS "=" bysplist )
```

Notice how these refer to "lists" of values, and the spec seems to indicate all values can be separated by commas.  For example, BYMONTH=1,2,3 would mean January, February and March.

However, when I attempt to generate occurrences of a RRULE like this one:

```
FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=SU,MO,TU;BYSETPOS=1;BYMONTH=2,3
```

I would expect to get yearly occurrences on Sunday, Monday, and Tuesday, in February and March.

However, these libraries only return a single occurrence matching the first day/month in the list.  So if we assigned a start date of February 4, 2018 and generated occurrences for the next several years, we would only get February 4, 2018, February 3, 2019, February 2, 2020, etc.  No occurrence would be generated for Mondays or Tuesdays, or any dates in March.

Can someone shed some light on whether this is a bug or actually expected behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone shed some light on whether this is a bug or actually expected behavior?

I'm the author of [php-rrule](https://github.com/rlanvin/php-rrule), so thanks for using my lib! I can shed some light easily: you have `BYSETPOS=1` which *explicitly* restrict the resultset to the first occurrence of the list. So yes, this is the expected behavior. Why did you add `BYSETPOS` if you wanted everything?

Comment: First, THANKS for creating such a useful library!  Second, the reason for BYSETPOS was: I thought it indicated which week(s) to use.  This rrule generator https://www.textmagic.com/free-tools/rrule-generator seems to support that.  I assumed that BYSETPOS=1 meant "all occurrences in week 1", in contrast to "all occurrences in the entire month/year". Per that example site, the following rule would generate occurrences for the second Sunday of January: FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=SU;BYSETPOS=2;BYMONTH=1.  Notice how BYSETPOS indicates the 2nd Sunday.  Obviously I'm not understanding the syntax.

Comment: So how does BYSETPOS apply to the other rule properties?  Which one does it modify?

Comment: I wrote a getOccurrencesBetween() function.  If you like, I can add it to the project.

Comment: `BYSETPOS` is a bit tricky. It specifies which occurrence(s) to keep once the set has been calculated, and this is based on the frequency. In your example, with a `FREQ=YEARLY` the calculated set will be all the occurrences of *a year* (i.e. Sundays, Mondays, and Tuesdays, in February and March). It'll only select the first (or the second if you had BYSETPOS=2). It absolutely does *not* mean "all occurrences in week 1". Think of `BYSETPOS` has a filter that is applied after everything else has been calculated.

Comment: Also, there is already a `getOccurrencesBetween` method, but thanks for asking :-) Feel free to open a pull request if you have any other improvement!